# What is the best way to make a non-blocking HTTP request using Reactor WebClient and deserialize the response to an object?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactor, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I have experience with asynchronous libraries like Vert.x but new to Reactor/WebFlux specifically. I want to expose a single endpoint on a web application that when hit, turns around and calls another web service, parses the response into a Java object, then accesses fields within the object and does something with them. I am using WebClient to make the HTTP call and Jackson ObjectMapper to deserialize it. My code looks roughly like this (note: `RequestUtil.safeDeserialize` just uses Jackson to parse the string body into an object and returns `Optional<Object>` which is why I have an additional `map` step afterwards):

```
    public Mono<String> function(final String param) {
        final String encodedRequestBody = RequestUtil.encodeRequestBody(param);
        final Mono<Response> responseMono = webClient.post()
                .uri("/endpoint")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + basicAuthHeader)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromPublisher(Mono.just(encodedRequestBody), String.class))
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(clientResponseMono -> clientResponseMono.bodyToMono(String.class))
                .map(RequestUtil::safeDeserialize)
                .map(resp -> resp.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Failed to deserialize Oscar response!")));

        responseMono.subscribe(response -> {
            // Pull out some of the fields from the `Response` type object and do something with them
        });

        return responseMono.map(Response::aStringField);
    }
```

After performance testing this code against an identical application that follows the exact same logic, but makes the HTTP call via the blocking Java11 `HttpClient` class, I see almost no difference between the two -- in fact, the `WebClient` implementation is slightly *less* performant than the blocking implementation.

Clearly I made a mistake somewhere either with the code or my mental model of what's going on here, so any help/advice is very appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Based on the advice in @Toerktumlare's response, I have updated the function to the following:

```
    public Mono<String> function(final String param) {
        final Mono<String> encodedRequestBody = RequestUtil.encodeRequestBodyToMono(param);
        final Mono<Response> responseMono = webClient.post()
                .uri("/endpoint")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + basicAuthHeader)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(encodedRequestBody, String.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Response.class);

        return responseMono.flatMap(response -> {
            final String field = response.field();
            // Use `field` to do something that would produce a log message
            logger.debug("Field is: {}", field);
            return Mono.just(field);
        });
}
```

When running this code, I don't see any logging. This makes me think that the HTTP call isn't actually happening (or completing in time?) because when I use `subscribe` with the same `WebClient` code, I can successfully print out fields from the response. What am I missing?

Edit2: This function is being used to serve responses to an endpoint (a few lines of code are omitted for conciseness):

```
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routerFunction(ResponseHandler handler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/my/endpoint")
                .and(RequestPredicates.accept(MediaType.ALL)), handler::endpoint);
    }
 

    public Mono<ServerResponse> endpoint(ServerRequest request) {
        // Pull out a comma-separated list from the request
        final List<String> params = Arrays.asList(fieldFromRequest.split(","));

        // For each param, call function(param), roll into list
        List<Mono<String>> results = params.stream()
                .map(nonBlockingClient::function)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Check to see if any of the requests failed
        if (results.size() != params.size()) {
            return ServerResponse.status(500).build();
        }

        logger.debug("Success");
        return ServerResponse.ok().build();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the your problem is with the usage of `subscribe`.

A `consumer` will `subscribe` to a `producer`. Your backend application is a `producer` which makes the calling client the `consumer`. Which means, its usually the calling client that should be `subscribing` not you.

What you are doing now is basically `consuming` your own `production`. Which is in a way blocking.

In general you should never subscribe in a webflux application, unless your application for example calls an api and then consumes the response (for instance saves it in a database etc). The one the initiates the call, is in general the `subscriber`.

I would rewrite the last part and drop the `subscribe`:

```
return responseMono.flatMap(response -> {
        final string = doSomething(response);
        return OscarGuacResponse.aStringField(string);
    });
```

Also i see that in `RequestUtil::safeDeserializez` you return an `Optional<T>` i would instead look into returning either a `Mono#empty`, or `Mono#error` as the return type to be able to use the many error operators that are available in webflux for instance `switchIfEmpty`, `onErrorContinue`, `defaultIfEmpty` etc etc. There is an [entire chapter](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling) on error handling in the reactor documentation.

Also maybe look into using `flatMap` instead of `map` in many places. To understand the differences between these two you can [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65692723/1840146).

Also, when looking at performance later on, you should understand that when you measure webflux performance, you need to look at such things as memory footprint and number of threads, compared to non-blocking applications. You might not see any performance gain when it comes to speed, but instead see that the application uses a lot less threads which in turn means a smaller memory footprint which is a gain itself.

Update:

You are trying to code regular java when doing reactive programming which will not work. Why your code is not working is because you are ["breaking the chain"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61541336/1840146).

I wrote this without an IDE, so it might not compile, but you should get the understanding of it. You always need to chain on the previous, and things like java streams etc are usually not needed in reactive programming.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> endpoint(ServerRequest request) {
    final List<String> params = Arrays.asList(fieldFromRequest.split(","));
    return Flux.fromIterable(params)
               .flatMap(param -> nonBlockingClient.function(param))
               .collectList()
               .flatMap(list -> {
                   if (list.size() != params.size()) {
                       return ServerResponse.status(500).build();
                   }
                   return ServerResponse.ok().build();
               })
}
```

This is basic reactive programming and i **HIGHLY** suggest you go through the ["getting started section"](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#intro-reactive) of the reactor documentation so you understand the basics, because if you are going to code regular java in a reactive application, you are going to have a bad time.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments, I made the first change you suggested (using Mono instead of Optional when deserializing) but I'm still having an issue converting `subscribe` to `flatMap`. The condensed return statement is: `return responseMono.flatMap(r -> {String a = r.Field(); logger.debug(a); return Mono.just(a); });` and I never see the logging statement get printed, whereas when I use `subscribe` I see the HTTP call complete and can print out data from the response as well. Am I missing something?

Comment: I've updated my original post with the new code I'm using, any advice/help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the code got executed before, because you where basically "blocking" the code, and if your code blocks, it is guaranteed to run. if you dont see your log statement means that you are somewhere in your code "breaking the chain". So you are somewhere not chaining on a returned `Mono` or `Flux`. The updated code you have posted above is fully legit reactive code (except that your function needs a better then function >D). So i would look at the code either calling this, or the code after and see if there is something there.

Comment: Thank you again so much for the response, I again edited the OP with the code that calls this function. I'm streaming over a list of input params and passing each one to my `function`, then returning a response to the client. Is the problem that I'm calling `function` which returns `Mono<String>`, but rolling the results into a `List` instead of chaining off the `Mono`s? If so, any idea how I would implement a loop operation on a collection of inputs, pass each to `function`, wait for them all to complete then return HTTP 200 if so?

Comment: i have updated the answer, this question is answered now, no lengthy discussions in comments pls

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to modify my service and now everything seems to work as expected. I accepted your answer, thanks again for the help :)